# Weird colors in normals map

Tags: normals, texture-baking

so everytime i try to bake normals i get these weired colors
[image]

Things worth mentioning

1. im using blender (blender cycles)
2. ray distance = .1

**Blend file**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h5ofCYo1R8Fzeo7yEXAsSBvmBSD0_Aqz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to the site :) For future reference we prefer .blends to be uploaded [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599)

Answer (score 2):

If you increase the bake *Ray Distance* to, for example, a value of 3, it works. It looks like it's because your objects are big on the scene, if I decrease them and apply scale it will need a lower value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i've tried but still doesn't seems to work(same problem)

Comment: it's weird because if I open your file and just change the Ray Distance, it works fine. By the way, you're not in Blender Internal, you are in Cycles.