# Normals Not Applying Correctly Onto Model (Strange Placement)

Tags: normals, baking

When applying some baked normals, both object and tangent baked, onto my model (Shown Below or Above), the normals show up on the model; however, the normals are not in the correct location. After much research, testing, and personal troubleshooting, I found that nothing helped. Please Help.

File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mD_Q0tBSlvyyJ6P8mV2lN0pPaThkzCPD

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129299/weird-colors-in-normals-map

Comment: Please upload your file. From the looks of it, it seems like you have set the ray distance too high so that it ray-casts to the opposite leg(?).

Answer (score 0):

Hi its pretty hard to tell without the project file or a Uv overlay, but it doesn't look like a mapping issue. Looks like there were ray distance issues in the actual bake, try slightly increasing the the Ray Dist value. If that doesn't work try also using a cage mesh and check if there are any intersections in you model

Comment: Just added the file.